# airflow "task exited with return code -9"

Tags: amazon-web-services, mwaa

i recently started testing my dags on AWS MWAA version 2.7.2 some of the tasks of dags are failing due to same error "airflow 'task exited with return code -9'".can i have a solution to overcome

i need to upgrade aws mwaa from 2.o.2 to 2.7.2 as 2.o.2 is going to be deprecated, for that i created new mwaa with version 2.7.2 and started running dags (checking working condition of dags in newer version).
i need a solution to overcome this error "airflow 'task exited with return code -9'"

Comment: I have the same issue since upgrading to MWAA 2.7.2. I think you'd have to change the number of retries and only retry when you get this error message (using on_retry_callback)